# Jmeter: What to add in HTTP Cookie Manager?

Tags: http, cookies, jmeter

There are following column names under "User-defined cookies":
1. Name
2. Value
3. Domain
4. Path
5. Secure

What I should enter in all above mentioned fields and how it is useful?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Cookie Manager is smart enough to **automatically** take care about cookies. Being added and enabled it fetches cookies from [Set-Cookie](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) response header and adds them to the next request enabling client-side state management, cookie based authentication, etc. Moreover, it provides access to cookies via [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) assuming `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` property is set in *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation).

In regards to fields like Name, Value, Domain, etc. - this way you can define your own custom cookies or override existing cookies if i.e. you need to hard-wire a request to this or that node behind the load balancer, simulate activity of certain user, whatever.

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) guide for more details on this useful test element.